# Perl: How to return top line from file

Tags: perl

I have a file with this data:

---

```
elapsed_time         disk_reads          sqlid

2            316         c1532tkq9mc0md5

1            0       lwabizjrfgcnkt1bb5k

1            240         jusnum7hy4

0            5       s69t8ze3rtuxik9s4

0            0       w4la6it246coqfqa

33           0       18wpwk3ync5c

0            0       8lhgyx4z43xk5dl4y7z

0            0       hqbhyibw94ns06mhrbz

30           0       ruu3oacuq1bjzo

20           0       vbk1zfvmk187

2            316         ll1ultl7ttpikuzqo9j

1            0       ftc6ix6lahetwsxfo
```

---

I want to return in Perl the 3 lines with TOP elapsed time:

```
30           0       ruu3oacuq1bjzo

20           0       vbk1zfvmk187

33           0       18wpwk3ync5c
```

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Does it have to be Perl? `sort -g | tail -n 3` could do this quite easily.

Comment: Are all the empty lines on purpose?

Comment: Voting to close: The solution is readily apparent to anyone who has read just the first few chapters of any learning Perl book. I'm not one who usually screams ***RTFM!***, but this is really, really basic Perl stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reads all lines, sorts by elapse time descending, and prints first three,

```
perl -ne '/^(\d+)/ or next;push @r,[$_,$1] }{ print map { ($i++ < 3) ? $$_[0]:() } sort{$$b[1]<=>$$a[1]} @r' file
```